# Strange actual parameter assignment in shiny's renderPlot

Tags: shiny, output, rendering

When using a for loop to render some plots I obtained results I didn't understand. All plots became equal to the (intended) last one. I hope to make this more clear in the example below. Note the plot1 shows a '6' (the last one), not a '5' (as intended).
Can anyone explain this and/or give a solution avoid this kind of behaviour.
shiny ui:

```
shinyUI (fluidPage(
fluidRow (
    column (6, plotOutput ('plot1', height = "180px")),
    column (6, plotOutput ('plot2', height = "180px"))
),
fluidRow (
    column (6, plotOutput ('plot3', height = "180px")),
    column (6, plotOutput ('plot4', height = "180px"))
)
))
```

shiny server:

```
shinyServer (function (input, output, session) {
require (ggplot2)
plotId      <- c('plot1', 'plot2', 'plot3', 'plot4')
pw          <- initPlotWindows ()   
output[['plot1']] <- renderPlot ({pw[[1]]})
output[['plot2']] <- renderPlot ({pw[[2]]})
output[['plot3']] <- renderPlot ({pw[[3]]}) 
output[['plot4']] <- renderPlot ({pw[[4]]})
id  <- 'plot1'
i   <- 5
output[[id]] <- renderPlot ({pw[[i]]})
id  <- 'plot3'
i   <- 6
# output[[id]] <- renderPlot ({pw[[i]]})
})  

initPlotWindows <- function () {
    pw          <- vector (mode = 'list', length = 6)                           # plot window data
    for (i in 1:6)  pw[[i]] <- p_empty (plotN = i)
    pw
}
p_empty <- function (plotN) {
    p <- ggplot()
    p <- p + annotate("text", label = plotN, x = .5, y = .5, size = 20, colour = "grey")
    p <- p + theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.title.x=element_blank())
    p <- p + theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank())
    p
}
```

Resulting output. Plot1 contains a 6 not a 5!
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this happens is because shiny does not execute your server side code line by line. Shiny executes all of the non-reactive code once at the beginning. But `renderPlot()` and other reactive code will only run when it is necessary. (when they are called)

So what happened is, it assigned 5, and then 6 to `i`, and only rendered the plot afterwards.

```
output[[id]] <- renderPlot ({
    print("section D")
    pw[[i]]})
```

You can check it pretty easily in the R console using the `print()` function:

```
shinyServer (function (input, output, session) {
  print("section A")
  require (ggplot2)
  plotId      <- c('plot1', 'plot2', 'plot3', 'plot4')
  pw          <- initPlotWindows ()

  output[['plot1']] <- renderPlot ({
    print("section B1")
    pw[[1]]})
  output[['plot2']] <- renderPlot ({
    print("section B2")
    pw[[2]]})
  output[['plot3']] <- renderPlot ({
    print("section B3")
    pw[[3]]}) 
  output[['plot4']] <- renderPlot ({
    print("section B4")
    pw[[4]]})
  print("section C")
  id  <- 'plot1'
  i   <- 5
  output[[id]] <- renderPlot ({
    print("section D")
    pw[[i]]})
  print("section E")
  id  <- 'plot3'
  i   <- 6
  # output[[id]] <- renderPlot ({pw[[i]]})
})
```

Console output:

```
[1] "section A"
[1] "section C"
[1] "section E"
[1] "section B1"
[1] "section B2"
[1] "section B3"
[1] "section B4"
[1] "section D"
```

### Edit:

As for the `output[[id]]`, `id` gets evaluated at the beginning, so `output[[id]]` becomes `output[[plot1]]`. But `pw[[i]]` is only evaluated when shiny asks the plot to render, which is after the value has been set to 5 and then to 6.

If you want plot1 to show 5, then you could assign `id` outside of `renderPlot()`, and assign `i` inside of `renderPlot()`:

```
id  <- 'plot1'
  output[[id]] <- renderPlot ({
    i <- 5
    pw[[i]]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you GyD,
From your answer I conclude that a normal for-loop is not possible. The running variable 'i' would than be defined outside and not inside renderPlot().
So it seems that I have to use eval (parse()) for at least renderPlot().
A for-loop like:

```
for ( i in 1:4) {
        pltId <- paste ('plot', i, sep='')
        output[[pltId]] <- renderPlot ({pw[i]})
    }
```

would then become (using eval(parse()) for the whole assignment):

```
for ( i in 1:4) {
        eval (parse (text = paste ("output[['plot", i, "']] <- renderPlot ({pw[", i, "]})", sep='')))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer should work, but you could generate both the UI elements and the server side with loops. (don't know if that interests you)

I am not a huge fan of `for` loops in R, so I'm using `lapply`.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

# I want to plot these elements

vec <- c(5, 2, 3, 4)

# Defining some functions

initPlotWindows <- function () {
  pw          <- vector (mode = 'list', length = 6)                           # plot window data
  for (i in vec)  pw[[i]] <- p_empty (plotN = i)
  pw
}
p_empty <- function (plotN) {
  p <- ggplot()
  p <- p + annotate("text", label = plotN, x = .5, y = .5, size = 20, colour = "grey")
  p <- p + theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.title.x=element_blank())
  p <- p + theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank())
  p
}

# Creating pw list
pw <- initPlotWindows()

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Creating UI from loop
  lapply(vec, function(i) {
    column(6, plotOutput(paste0('plot', i), height = "180px"))
  })
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  # Generating UI output from loop

  lapply(vec, function(i) {
    output[[paste0('plot', i)]] <- renderPlot({
      pw[[i]]
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```